Communication between AutoHotkey and Chrome Script (Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey)?
I've created a custom Tampermonkey script to control all videos in the current active Chrome Tab back/pause/forward/playback rates.
Now I'm trying to also use them from my Streamdeck while in a game on my other monitor.
I already got Streamdeck connected to AutoHotkey to call any function in AutoHotkey without using any weird hotkey combinations, by using an express server and a custom plugin for the streamdeck.
My question: Is it possible to somehow either receive, or if not possible, poll commands with a Tampermonkey script from a locally hosted SOMETHING?
I tried websocket, fetch, xmlhttprequest ... but always the same stuff... error with CORS I believe. It doesn't allow me to subscribe to or poll my locally hosted stuff.
I'm not experienced in the CORS stuff etc. Does anybody have a working js + ahk script that can somehow communicate or any alternative ideas on what I could try?
btw, I'm using ahk2, but ahk isn't the problem.

To improve clarity, I suggest using the word "stuff" less, and instead provide a specific description of what you mean.  Also, maybe be a little bit more clear about what you expect "locally hosted SOMETHING" to be.

well, thats the thing im asking tho. the STUFF and SOMETHING will basically be the answer to my question.
What can i use to communicate, what is the SOMETHING that should work. Websocket and Express didn't work for me, so i don't know what else to use. Or how i can work around CORS to still use any of those

Sounds like GM_xmlhttpRequest is what you need here.
